# Stop increasing of hibernate version column as child is not modified

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities which have one-to-one relationship Site and Address. Both the tables have hibernate version column. i am using `sitedao.save(siteEntity)` to save, which saves both site and address.

When I am performing an update operation on site entity fields and persist, both site and address entity versions are getting updated because of @UpdateTimestamp annotation on lastModifiedAt column in the address table. This column makes the row dirty and increases the version column data (lastModifiedAt is coming from  BaseEntity)

How can we avoid version increment in the address column

Comment: You can't. Why do want to avoid that. The version field is only handled by Hibernate and shouldn't be used for anything else

Comment: I got this solution from the below link. 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic
setting this annotation @OptimisticLock(excluded = true) on lastModifiedAt column solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `CascadeType.MERGE` between them, and save these two entities separately.
Then you could make a query to check if new address is different from the old one and only then save the address to update its version.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from the below link.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic
setting this annotation @OptimisticLock(excluded = true) on lastModifiedAt column solve this issue.